# Print on specific coordinates

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a card that has10cm height and 15cm width. I am trying to print a string on the following coordinates: 1,5cm from top to bottom and 3,5cm from the left to right. Until now i tried to use the bellow code that i found on msdn but with no luck. The code that i am using is :

```
System.IO.StreamReader fileToPrint;
System.Drawing.Font printFont;
private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string printPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
   fileToPrint = new System.IO.StreamReader(printPath + @"\myFile.txt");
    printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10);
    printDocument1.Print();
     fileToPrint.Close();
  }

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  float yPos = 0f;
  int count = 0;
  float leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
  float topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
  string line = null;
  float linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height/printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);
 while (count < linesPerPage)
   {
      line = fileToPrint.ReadLine();
      if (line == null)
    {
       break;
    }
      yPos = topMargin + count * printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);
      e.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos, new      StringFormat());
       count++;
    }
     if (line != null)
   {
       e.HasMorePages = true;
   }
 }
```

Comment: `PrintDocument` is only for Windows Forms. It doesn't even make sense for web forms. Were you trying to print on the user's printer, or on the server's printer?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. I am running the web app on localhost and i am trying to print on the user's printer, this printer is also a local machine.